# Is there any interactive tool on web to understand common code bases?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

I am modifying the code for glibc 2.5. Now since glibc is large and complex, I need to have a really good tool, to see interaction of different parts of the code. I am using [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/) for this purpose, but Understood is only valid for 15 days. Afterwards you have to buy it.

So my question is, on web, are there sites where you can interactively understand common code bases such as glibc, gcc, linux kernel etc. I mean where you could search for some function, and then click on a function call to see its definition and such other useful features. I have used [Koders.com](http://www.koders.com/), but it will only display the code, and is not interactive.

Comment: Basically, an alternative to Google Code Search (http://www.google.com/codesearch) which was, sadly, shut down. This here question may be of help: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/114629/is-there-an-alternative-to-google-code-search

Comment: There is limited version of code search online: http://code.google.com/codesearch - works only on sources hosted on code.google.com. But glibc should be there. Also you can look on [LXR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxr/) cross-reference tool which was written for Linux kernel.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) is good. You have to host it yourself though, it's not on the web.